# can´t create an apk with an ionic project

Tags: android, ionic-framework, apk

Hi im new in ionic and im trying to create an apk to in order to test my qr scanner project, but when I run the command ionic cordova build android --release
i got the following error output:

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

```
    :processReleaseManifest FAILED

    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 13.446 secs
    C:\Users\delacrga\Ionic projects\myApp\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml:19:5-65 Error:
    Element uses-permission#android.permission.CAMERA at AndroidManifest.xml:19:5-65 duplicated with element
    declared at AndroidManifest.xml:16:5-90
    C:\Users\delacrga\Ionic projects\myApp\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml:21:5-84 Error:
    Element uses-feature#android.hardware.camera at AndroidManifest.xml:21:5-84 duplicated with element declared at
    AndroidManifest.xml:17:5-85
    C:\Users\delacrga\Ionic projects\myApp\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Validation failed, exiting

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':processReleaseManifest'.
    > Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    C:\Users\delacrga\Ionic projects\myApp\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml:19:5-65 Error:
    Element uses-permission#android.permission.CAMERA at AndroidManifest.xml:19:5-65 duplicated with element
    declared at AndroidManifest.xml:16:5-90
    C:\Users\delacrga\Ionic projects\myApp\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml:21:5-84 Error:
    Element uses-feature#android.hardware.camera at AndroidManifest.xml:21:5-84 duplicated with element declared at
    AndroidManifest.xml:17:5-85
    C:\Users\delacrga\Ionic projects\myApp\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Validation failed, exiting

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':processReleaseManifest'.
    > Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Could someone helpme with this?

output:

```
C:\Users\delacrga\Ionic projects\myApp>ionic cordova build android --prod --release -- -- --keystore=filename.keystore --alias=myalias
Running app-scripts build: --prod --iscordovaserve --externalIpRequired --nobrowser

[08:52:04]  build prod started ...
[08:52:04]  clean started ...
[08:52:04]  clean finished in 10 ms
[08:52:04]  copy started ...
[08:52:04]  ngc started ...
[08:52:15]  ngc finished in 11.48 s
[08:52:15]  preprocess started ...
[08:52:16]  deeplinks started ...
[08:52:16]  deeplinks finished in 63 ms
[08:52:16]  optimization started ...
[08:52:16]  copy finished in 11.85 s
[08:52:26]  optimization finished in 10.47 s
[08:52:26]  preprocess finished in 10.54 s
[08:52:26]  webpack started ...
[08:52:32]  webpack finished in 5.46 s
[08:52:32]  sass started ...
[08:52:32]  uglifyjs started ...
[08:52:33]  sass finished in 1.22 s
[08:52:33]  cleancss started ...
[08:52:35]  cleancss finished in 1.93 s
[08:52:42]  uglifyjs finished in 10.23 s
[08:52:42]  postprocess started ...
[08:52:42]  postprocess finished in 15 ms
[08:52:42]  lint started ...
[08:52:42]  build prod finished in 37.83 s
> cordova build android --release -- --keystore=filename.keystore --alias=myalias
× Running command - failed!

[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android --release -- --keystore=filename.keystore --alias=myalias
        (exit code 1):

        ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\delacrga\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
        JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_131
        Subproject Path: CordovaLib
        The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use
        Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at build_amlj4yw9chmdse17z8bfqqws2.run(C:\Users\delacrga\Ionic
        projects\myApp\platforms\android\build.gradle:139)

        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * Where:
        Build file 'C:\Users\delacrga\Ionic projects\myApp\platforms\android\build.gradle' line: 289

        * What went wrong:
        A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
        > Keystore file does not exist: C:\Users\delacrga\Ionic projects\myApp\platforms\android\..\..\filename.keystore

        * Try:
        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

        BUILD FAILED

        Total time: 4.175 secs
        Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * Where:
        Build file 'C:\Users\delacrga\Ionic projects\myApp\platforms\android\build.gradle' line: 289

        * What went wrong:
        A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
        > Keystore file does not exist: C:\Users\delacrga\Ionic projects\myApp\platforms\android\..\..\filename.keystore

        * Try:
        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Answer (score 3):

By any chance if you have two different plugins installed which asks permission for the camera i.e. cordova-plugin-qrscanner and phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner together, it will cause this issue.

Remove either of the plugin by

```
ionic cordova plugin remove phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner
```

or

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-qrscanner
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.@Jay is right. Because my ionic project have two different plugins installed which asks permission for the camera. cordova-plugin-qrscanner and cordova-plugin-cszbar,Remove either of the plugin then working.